# Can't fully see MDI-children forms inside Main Form

Tags: delphi

There is MDI-application which contains main form fMain and children forms- fChartAcc and fReal. 
Main form is maximized and client area of main form is limited in screen sizes. 
When children forms is opened, in client area of main form I can't see bottom part of children forms and appear horizontal scroll bars on childen forms. I want fully paste child form in client area of main form, **in screen sizes and, accordingly, in main form sizes** without need in horizontal scroll bar.

[child form at design time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lGBh.png)

[child form when app is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn1bd.png)

[Main form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpHwz.png)

Main form: Formstyle:MDIForm 
Childred forms:
Formstyle:MDIChild 
Align- alClient or alCustom 
Position-tried poDefaultPosOnly, poDefault, poDesigned
autoSize:false
tried settings of size of chilled forms place in procedures OnCreate, OnShow, OnResize but no success.

```
Main form: Formstyle:MDIForm 
Childred forms:  
  Formstyle:MDIChild 
  Align- alClient or alCustom 
  Position-tried poDefaultPosOnly, poDefault, poDesigned  
  autoSize:false
  tried settings of size of chilled forms place in procedures OnCreate, 
    OnShow, OnResize but no success.
```

**unit Umain;**

```
    procedure TFmain.MDIChildCreated(const childHandle : THandle);
    begin
      mdiChildrenTabs.Tabs.AddObject(TForm(FindControl(childHandle)).Caption, TObject(childHandle));
      mdiChildrenTabs.TabIndex := -1 + mdiChildrenTabs.Tabs.Count;
    end;

    procedure TFmain.MDIChildDestroyed(const childHandle : THandle);
    var
      idx: Integer;
    begin
      idx := mdiChildrenTabs.Tabs.IndexOfObject(TObject(childHandle));
      mdiChildrenTabs.Tabs.Delete(idx);
    end;



    procedure TFmain.NChartAccClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      application.CreateForm(TfChartAcc, fChartAcc);
     fChartAcc.Show;
    end;

    procedure TFmain.realisatia1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      application.CreateForm(TFgas, Fgas);
      Fgas.Show;
    end;

    end.
```

**unit UChartAcc;**

```
    procedure TfChartAcc.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    begin
     action:=caFree;
    end;


    procedure TfChartAcc.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
     Left:=0;
     Top:=Fmain.Toolbar.Height+Fmain.MDIChildrentabs.height;
     Height:=Fmain.ClientHeight-Fmain.Toolbar.Height-Fmain.MDIChildrentabs.height-Fmain.StatusBar.Height-2*GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);
     Width:=Fmain.ClientWidth- 2*GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);

      FMain.MDIChildCreated(self.Handle);
    end;


    procedure TfChartAcc.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    begin
     FMain.MDIChildDestroyed(self.Handle);
    end;

    procedure TfChartAcc.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
    begin
     {
     Left:=0;
     Top:=Fmain.Toolbar.Height+Fmain.MDIChildrentabs.height;
     Height:=Fmain.ClientHeight-Fmain.Toolbar.Height-Fmain.MDIChildrentabs.height-Fmain.StatusBar.Height-2*GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);
     Width:=Fmain.ClientWidth- 2*GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);
     }
    end;





    procedure TfChartAcc.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    begin
     Left:=0;
     Top:=Fmain.Toolbar.Height+Fmain.MDIChildrentabs.height;
     Height:=Fmain.ClientHeight-Fmain.Toolbar.Height-Fmain.MDIChildrentabs.height-Fmain.StatusBar.Height-2*GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);
     Width:=Fmain.ClientWidth- 2*GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);
    end;

    end.
```

[Project 1](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wQRFXLwDREQrWwmN3bucXTi8qamPGPAl)

Comment: Tom Brunberg, I edit question- added screenshots. 
You wrote:"Have you considered what happens if a user has a different size screen?". Yes, I want such solutions that resizes child forms when screen size is changed.

Comment: Tom Brunberg, thank you very much for you attempt to help. 1) On compile(F9) it is created in maximum sizes, on full desktop. After that I make main form smaller for you, for good looking. After that I create child form. 2) I insert you code in OnCreate of child form (fChartAcc) but nothing changed.

Comment: Tom Brunberg, my settings fot left, top, height and bottom gets the same results: height 881, width 1276. BoundsRect property gets the same (0,0,1276, 881). What is the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get current `ClientRect` of a `MDI` main form you can use `WinApi.Windows.GetClientRect()` function like this (adapted to your `uChartAcc` unit):

Add a new procedure to the `FChartAcc` form, e.g. MyAdjustSize. *I changed the name, because `AdjustSize()` is a virtual method of `TWinControl`*:

```
procedure TFChartAcc.MyAdjustSize;
var
  r: TRect;
begin
  if not WinApi.Windows.GetClientRect(FMain.ClientHandle, r) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  BoundsRect := r;
end;
```

The window referred to by `ClientHandle` already excludes menu bars, tool bars etc. that are aligned to the sides of the form, so no need for further calculations.

Replace previously suggested code from `TFChartAcc.FormCreate`, with a call to `MyAdjustSize`:

```
procedure TFChartAcc.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyAdjustSize;

  FMain.MDIChildCreated(self.Handle);
end;
```

Then in the main form add an event handler for the `OnResize` event as follows. The purpose is to call the `MyAdjustSize` procedure for **all currently existing** child forms:

```
procedure TFMain.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
var
  ix: integer;
  ob: TWinControl;
begin
  for ix := 0 to MDIChildrenTabs.Tabs.Count-1 do
  begin
      ob := FindControl(THandle(MDIChildrenTabs.Tabs.Objects[ix]));
      if ob is TFChartAcc then
        TFChartAcc(ob).MyAdjustSize;
  end;
end;
```

Because all child windows are already sized correctly, we don't need to call `MyAdjust` when selecting another child form.

```
procedure TFMain.mdiChildrenTabsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ix: integer;
  ob: TWinControl;
begin
  ix := MDIChildrenTabs.TabIndex;
  if ix > -1 then
  begin
    ob := FindControl(THandle(MDIChildrenTabs.Tabs.Objects[ix]));
    ob.BringToFront;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Tom Brunberg, the same. DDBMemos and DBEdit, localized on the bottom of chiled form, don't  appear in clientarea of main form.

Comment: You asked (expressed a wish): *I want children forms equal to client area size of main form, not more.* I have no idea why you now start to speak about `DBMemo` and `DBEdit` components. I've told you how to sort out the `FChartAcc` form size. If you have other problems, please post new questions.

Comment: Tom Brunberg, on the child form from top to bottom are placed: Panel1, dbgrid, dbedit and dbmemo.  In client area of main form I see Panel and part of dbgrid. dbedit and dbmemo don't appear on desktop area.   
You may see project.

Comment: Tom Brunberg, Windowstate of main form is set to 'wsMaximized'.

Comment: Tom Brunberg, It all works brilliantly. Thanks for having my back.  :D :D :D

Comment: @basti It works even only with `ob.BringToFront` since `BringToFront` is declared in, and inherited already from `TControl`, and further since `ob` is a `TWinControl`, also inherited from TControl. If you need to access any members declared in `TFChartAcc`, like e.g. `MyAdjust()` then you have to cast `ob` as such. But hey, I need to remind you that SO works as a "One Question - One Answer" site. If you have other questions, do not post them here in comments, hit the [Ask Question] button and write them as new questions and I'll take a look.

Comment: @basti I think we should clean up all those comments that are now irrelevant, as the actual matter has been sorted out. When you move your mouse over your own comments, a deletion circle-cross appears at the end.